# Why is the QGIS 2.2 database tab missing?

Tags: qgis, postgis, installation, ubuntu

I have recently installed QGIS-2.2.0 but the Database tab in the top-menu bar is missing. It looks the main reason is missing libgdal1h library. But when I am installing it, it's removing Postgresql-9.3, PostGIS-2.1 and PgAdminIII (which initially asked for libgdal1 library during installation) before installation. I want PostGIS to connect to from QGIS Database tab (Database Manager). I guess, there is a conflict between libgdal1h and libgdal1.

I am on Ubuntu-12.04.

Comment: How did you install QGIS? Where are you getting libgdal1h in order to install it (it's not present on a clean 12.04)? If you're using e.g. both the pgdg and ubuntugis repositories, it looks like they do indeed currently conflict, and I'm afraid I'm not sure of a workaround.

Comment: m sorry for being late. I guess there is some problem with my OS.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an old question but I had this issue recently on Fedora 21, with the missing database tab. Although I could still access the POSTGIS layer and navigate that, it turned out that Fedora had removed the qgis-python package which is required for the database UI.

Comment: That's not Fedora-specific. I also noted that new QGIS versions on Ubuntu did not update qgis-python by default.