# libgdal1 and libgdal1h conflict

Tags: postgis, gdal, grass-gis

I am on Ubuntu 14.04. When I am installing PostGIS-2.1, it's asking for libgdal1 library. But when I am installing libgdal1, it's removing Grass and GDAL.

Can someone please guide me how to install Grass, GDAL and PostGIS?

Comment: Duplicate to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99788/qgis-2-2-0-database-tab-missing

Comment: http://scigeo.org/articles/howto-install-latest-geospatial-software-on-linux.html

Comment: How are you installing PostGIS? In 14.04, the postgis package depends upon libgdal1h, not libgdal1: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/postgis - so you presumably are not installing it on a clean install.

Comment: Yaa, you are right. Somehow I have installed too many libraries and they are conflicting. https://gist.github.com/djq/2846196 link helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem.  PostGIS wanted libgdal1 and QGIS wanted libgdal1h.  The problem was that I had my Repo for QGIS set to the main QGIS site, and Postgresql set to their main site.  Postgresql kept wanting to upgrade past what QGIS wanted.  Finally something gave and I ended up with circular conflicts between the two.

I ended up backing up my Postgres/PostGis databases. Then uninstalling just about everything GIS on my system.  I had to do a "Complete" uninstall of Postgresql 9.1, because it was not uninstalling cleanly.  Then I changed my repo over to [UbuntuGIS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGIS) and reinstalled everything from there.  Restored my databases, and all was good.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation and solution. Although I have already solved this issue long ago but I wasn't sure why this all happened before you explained things nicely. Regards!